# Fetch Twitter Content using jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery

I'm not able to fetch the tweets from twitter.com using jquery ajax call

I'm getting 403 forbidden error.

PFB the code,

```
$.getJSON('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/' + user + '.json?count=10&callback=?', function (data) {});
```

Please let me know how to fetch the tweets using jquery, Solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, the API requires SSL.

So you have to have SSL installed on your webserver.

Comment: Hi Amit, I want to build this app with phone gap. So, should i need to have SSL?